# Fizzbuzz counters 1-20 and check for divideables and not dividables

Tags: java, eclipse, counter, divider, fizzbuzz

So i have a problem with java that when i run the program the console prints out this

```
"12Fizz4BuzzFizz78FizzBuzz11Fizz1314FizzBuzz1617Fizz19Buzz"
```

what i want it to do is , if its dividable with BOTH 3 and 5 then print out fizzbuz

if divideable with 3 print out fizz
if dividable with 5 print out Buzz

My code looks like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


        for(int i=1; i<=20; i++)

        {
            if (i % 3==0 && i % 5==0) // fizzbuzz
                System.out.print("FizzBuzz");
            else if (i % 3 == 0)//fizz coutner
                System.out.print("Fizz");
            else if (i % 5 == 0)// buzz
                System.out.print("Buzz"); 
            else
                System.out.print(i);


        }
    }

}
```

could anyone tell me why my print looks like a shrek code with 78 and 1314 etc when i want it to stop
counting after 20?
and please explain the mistakes im pretty new to this =) thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
System.out.println(..);
```

instead of

```
System.out.print(..);
```

so that a new line is appended after each `print()` call

Comment: Thanks alot for the answere totally missed that sanbhat , now it looks a bit better but the printout now looks like this "12Fizz
4Buzz
Fizz
78Fizz
Buzz
11Fizz
1314FizzBuzz
1617Fizz
19Buzz" wich looks wrong cuz i dont want it to Count to 1617 im not sure how those numbers even got there

Comment: could it be that its skipping over the numbers thats not divideable by eather 3 and 5? so  1, 2 looks like 12? and 13,14 looks like 1314?if yes any idea how i can make it mark the begining of a new number?

Comment: Nevermind found it didnt have printLine at the last int i ; my bad thanks alot for the help guys